# Running local and remote/server xPages

Tags: xpages

In my xPages application, I have multiple data stores defined and since it asks which server the data store is located, you define either local or a server.  But this application needs to have both since some users don't have Notes client software and will use it over the internet and others are remote with no internet connection but local software (will replicate all DBs each day).  How does the xPage know to use the server or local databases?

Comment: Is this in XPiNC or browser? And if XPiNC, what configuration (i.e. is the application specifically enabled to run as XPages application on server (on launch tab, "Run server-based XPages apps directly on server" checkbox)

Comment: I take it you're talking about the Launch tab in Application Properties.  I don't see a checkbox for that option.  Under Web Browser Launch, I've told it to open a view xPage.  But how will the "form" xPage know where to find the database, either local or server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you define data source database **without** server and just database's path.

If XPage runs on server then it will use the database on server.

If XPage runs in XPiNC then it will use the locale database or the database on server depending on option "Run server-based XPages apps directly on server".

XPages will always find the right database given that database's path is the same on server and client.

You can find the option on database's infobox:

[image]

Comment: Where is the "Run server-based XPages apps directly on server" located?  I don't see it in the Application Properties.

Comment: Knut, I appreciate your patience with me.  I see the option but it's greyed out.  Is there a setting somewhere else that is causing this?

Comment: It is greyed out if database is **locally** as you can't "run XPages app directly on server". You can set this option for databases on server only (= replica on server).

Answer (score 0):

XPages applications running on the server cannot access local NSFs stored on a user's laptop / PC. The code is not running in the browser, it's running on the remote server, which has no context to identify the current user's locally-stored NSF data.

If they have no internet connection, then without Domino Designer (and thus the HTTP task), you can't run XPages in a browser. Only Domino Designer has the HTTP task and XPages runtime to display the application in a browser. This is the reason for XPiNC, though it comes with its own challenges.